# Rails Multiple HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a rails application for an art exhibition website. At the moment  I have 4 models, Curator, Exhibition, Artist, and Artwork.

The application should work as follow, An Exhibition can be curated by many curators, an exhibition can display multiple artworks, an artwork can be displayed in many exhibitions, artist can own many artworks, and artworks belongs to one artist.

I'm a rail newb and I'm having difficulty building the relationship between the models. Can you tell me if I'm doing this right, or maybe there is a better way?

curator.rb

```
class Curator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :exhibitions
end
```

exhibition.rb

```
class Exhibition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :curators
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artworks
end
```

artwork.rb

```
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :exhibitions
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

artist.rb

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artworks
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: i think you have it right.  remember that you have to manually create the join tables in the db since you are using habtm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using has_many :through if you want to have validations on your relationships, use callbacks or want to add extra attributes.

If you want to have more information regarding this matter, this rails guide is great:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

Your HABTM looks fine though. If you run into any problem, it would be advisable to also reference your joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks right to me.. Do create the join tables naming convention would be:

```
curators_exhibitions

artworks_exhibitions
```

Hope you get the idea.

Also you would want to check out has_many :through in case you would want to do validations on top of the relationships!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did spend a bit of time researching about has_many :through vs has_and_belongs_to_many. Can you explain to me what you mean about the validation on top of the relationships? I still have a hard time comparing between the two.

Comment: Lets say you need a constraint where a curator can handle at most 3 exhibitions then you could put that in the join model which you create.. Defining the validations becomes cleaner in the application code that way.. Its usually recommended to use has_many :through, unless you are 100% sure that you won't have any validations introduced.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, I think it will be better to use has_many :through incase I need to extend the application in the future.